# JQuery with ASP.Net Master Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have been searching for an answer to this problem for hours and tried every example from a Google Search.

I am trying to upload a file using JQuery and it is part of an ASP.Net Master Page. When I test the script on a regular page it works fine. When I put it in a Master Page nothing happens.

Here is my Master Page

```
<head runat="server">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link href="css/grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
            .progressbar {
            width:400px;
            height:15px;
        }
            .progressbarlabel {
                width:400px;
                height:15px;
                position:absolute;
                text-align:center;
                font-size:medium;
                color:red;
            }
    </style>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is my content Page (Default.aspx)

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
                       <script>
                       $(document).ready(function () {
                           $("<%= uploadFile.ClientID %>").click(function (evt) {
                               var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                               var data = new FormData();
                               var files = $("#singleFile").get(0).files;
                               for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                                   data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                               }
                               xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                                   if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                       var progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
                                       $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", progress);
                                   }
                               }, false);
                               xhr.open("POST", "UploadBlob.ashx");
                               xhr.send(data);

                               $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                                   max: 100,
                                   change: function (evt, ui) {
                                       $("#progresslabel").text($("#progressbar").progressbar("value") + "%");
                                   },
                                   complete: function (evt, ui) {
                                       $("#progresslabel").text("Upload Complete!");
                                   },
                               });
                               evt.preventDefault();
                           });
                       });
    </script>
        <style>
            .progressbar {
            width:400px;
            height:15px;
        }
            .progressbarlabel {
                width:400px;
                height:15px;
                position:absolute;
                text-align:center;
                font-size:medium;
                color:red;
            }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                                                            <asp:FileUpload ID="singleFile" CssClass="btn-button" AllowMultiple="false" clientIdMode="Static" runat="server" Width="350px" />
                                                        <br />
                                                        <asp:Button ID="uploadFile" runat="server" Text="Upload Picture" clientIdMode="Static" />
                                                        <br />
                                                        <br />
                                                        <div id="progressbar" class="progressbar">
                                                        <div id="progresslabel" class="progressbarlabel">
                                                        </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
                                                   ControlToValidate="singleFile"
                                                   ErrorMessage="Only .jpg,.png,.gif Files are allowed" Font-Bold="True"
                                                   Font-Size="Medium"
                                                   ValidationExpression="(.*?)\.(jpg|png|gif|JPG|PNG|GIF)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the source code when viewed in Internet Explorer 11

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link href="css/grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
            .btn-facebook {
            background-color: hsl(246, 74%, 19%) !important;
            background-repeat: repeat-x;
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#6051e5", endColorstr="#130c54");
            background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6051e5), to(#130c54));
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6051e5, #130c54);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6051e5, #130c54);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #6051e5), color-stop(100%, #130c54));
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6051e5, #130c54);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6051e5, #130c54);
            background-image: linear-gradient(#6051e5, #130c54);
            border-color: #130c54 #130c54 hsl(246, 74%, 8.5%);
            color: #fff !important;
            text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        }
            .progressbar {
            width:400px;
            height:15px;
        }
            .progressbarlabel {
                width:400px;
                height:15px;
                position:absolute;
                text-align:center;
                font-size:medium;
                color:red;
            }
    </style>

                       <script>
                       $(document).ready(function () {
                           $("uploadFile").click(function (evt) {
                               var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                               var data = new FormData();
                               var files = $("#singleFile").get(0).files;
                               for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                                   data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                               }
                               xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                                   if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                       var progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
                                       $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", progress);
                                   }
                               }, false);
                               xhr.open("POST", "UploadBlob.ashx");
                               xhr.send(data);

                               $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                                   max: 100,
                                   change: function (evt, ui) {
                                       $("#progresslabel").text($("#progressbar").progressbar("value") + "%");
                                   },
                                   complete: function (evt, ui) {
                                       $("#progresslabel").text("Upload Complete!");
                                   },
                               });
                               evt.preventDefault();
                           });
                       });
    </script>
        <style>
            .progressbar {
            width:400px;
            height:15px;
        }
            .progressbarlabel {
                width:400px;
                height:15px;
                position:absolute;
                text-align:center;
                font-size:medium;
                color:red;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Test_Master.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="glgqpmWQpeJYyksP3N0nE40yIBqrlolte3Q3TAmhIXIWSQoToDwu9oSIjEshE7RJN5kPFvU8zK/9elBRlEYJ6H8Nub3kp1NRvFgFIBGK646ypYWQQbVQ0wUgibJ5vUV2zkU37hOutt/A0Djlnn33ymLh3u0MBiWftKRFDBKL9LUEuaf/1OAeawML3sZtDjmcHO1LOWfThjXaR5bBBDfcS8oFE48PM+cCXwlwfFbuICxKpPCN4+A7TG15cbtxrmEio+PCpDVj1rEKPujskSsisA==" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=pynGkmcFUV13He1Qd6_TZIW17XFPA72zFs-XRPFjAS8OLOo4XadI9kxFsKWqaIkPRqEQGnTTjZx4c0LHpR-xuA2&amp;t=635589255571259667" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=x2nkrMJGXkMELz33nwnakHKRERee4fvaxIO7XUfaQICWFXpUDlnpjBhXBfb1m-MvGxV8j2yp0JlWxbfaSC8c-djxGqBCRj0x7coUs4WUKR01&amp;t=635589255571259667" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;
return true;
}
//]]>
</script>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="3571F23D" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="PsSGfqyjblBZIkAOrBqDKDJdQzGutCcYXHVTdhFxxSoiDQH/c7pNPJxG639X0oxqRZ2jKCHIDXv53SlMTUIcmmVrySEtYl34ECjbNI8f3zYHcPZXRyyzi4KhPPFr0yrShVACQCfabsfmaj7shBVXGg==" />
</div>
            <div id="wrapper">
            <!--BEGIN: WRAPPER-->
            <header id="header">
                <!--BEGIN: HEADER-->
                <div class="row top-bar">
                    <div class="medium-6 columns">   
                        <div id="logo" class="logo">
                            <a href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                            <div id="fb_logout">
                                <input type="button" name="ctl00$FacebookButtonLogout" value="Log Out" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$FacebookButtonLogout&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" id="FacebookButtonLogout" class="btn-facebook" />
                            </div>                          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <nav id="navigation"><!-- BEGIN: Navigation -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <ul class="medium-12 columns">
                            <li>
                                <a href="Profile_Page.aspx">Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="my_rewards_page.html">My Rewards</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="shopping_cart_page.html">Shopping Cart</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="Test_Master.aspx">Services</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Careers</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <!-- END: Navigation -->
            </header>
            <!--END: Header-->

                                                            <input type="file" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$singleFile" id="singleFile" class="btn-button" style="width:350px;" />
                                                        <br />
                                                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uploadFile" value="Upload Picture" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uploadFile&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="uploadFile" />
                                                        <br />
                                                        <br />
                                                        <div id="progressbar" class="progressbar">
                                                        <div id="progresslabel" class="progressbarlabel">
                                                        </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_RegularExpressionValidator1" style="font-size:Medium;font-weight:bold;visibility:hidden;">Only .jpg,.png,.gif Files are allowed</span>

            <footer>
                Terms & Conditions     |    Privacy Policy     |    Copyright © 2015 Fingers Crossed Erie. All Rights Reserved.
            </footer>
        <!--END: CAMPUS TOUR-->
        </div>
        <!--END: WRAPPER-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/site.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Page_Validators =  new Array(document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_RegularExpressionValidator1"));
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var ContentPlaceHolder1_RegularExpressionValidator1 = document.all ? document.all["ContentPlaceHolder1_RegularExpressionValidator1"] : document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_RegularExpressionValidator1");
ContentPlaceHolder1_RegularExpressionValidator1.controltovalidate = "singleFile";
ContentPlaceHolder1_RegularExpressionValidator1.errormessage = "Only .jpg,.png,.gif Files are allowed";
ContentPlaceHolder1_RegularExpressionValidator1.evaluationfunction = "RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
ContentPlaceHolder1_RegularExpressionValidator1.validationexpression = "(.*?)\\.(jpg|png|gif|JPG|PNG|GIF)$";
//]]>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var Page_ValidationActive = false;
if (typeof(ValidatorOnLoad) == "function") {
    ValidatorOnLoad();
}

function ValidatorOnSubmit() {
    if (Page_ValidationActive) {
        return ValidatorCommonOnSubmit();
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
        //]]>
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: IE Options Image]

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Are you sure the `#uploadFile` is the actual client side ID for the element? Usually ASP.Net will have created something more exotic including the content panel ID. Use ` $("<%= uploadFile.ClientID %>")`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DanNick you can check the actual id of `uploadfile` in the source (using Developer Tools )and see what is the `id` of the Upload button

Comment: I updated the code based on suggestions. However the same issue is occurring. There is nothing else on the Default.aspx page except for the code above so nothing should come in conflict.

Comment: Please define "nothing happens", don't you even get an error message in the console ?

Comment: No I do not get any error message. I also turned off disable script debugging so that it shows any error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server Controls ID changes when used in Master Page lay out is used.

You can do any of the following things to make your code work.

1. Use `Html Control` Instead of `Server Control` :  Since you are not using any code behind methods you can change your controls to corresponding HTML control to retain their *ID* property. using HTML control will also put less load on your server.
   This controls

> 

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="singleFile" CssClass="btn-button"
 AllowMultiple="false"  runat="server" Width="350px" />

<asp:Button ID="uploadFile" runat="server" Text="Upload Picture" />
```

Changes to

```
 <input type="file" id = "singleFile" class = "btn-Button" width="350px" />
 <input type="button" id= "uploadFile" test="Upload Picture" />
```

2. Use ClientIdMode Static
   using this property retains your original ID of server control.

> 

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="singleFile" CssClass="btn-button" AllowMultiple="false"  runat="server" Width="350px"
clientIdMode="Static" />

<asp:Button ID="uploadFile" runat="server" Text="Upload Picture" clientIdMode="Static" />
```

Note: if you are using  this inside a repeater or grid, you need to use ClientIdMode = "Predictatble" to have unique Id in each row.

3. Use ClientId Mode Expression in Javascript on the Same Page.

Instead of using  `$("#uploadFile")` use  `$("<%= uploadFile.ClientID %>")` and use similar pattern for all your control IDs. This will get the dynamic ID for using in Javascript/JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

both of your controls are server side controls, i.e. Button and File Uploader so their IDs will change during page compilation, so use `$("<%= uploadFile.ClientID %>"` instead of `$("#uploadFile")` or simply add `ClientIdMode="Static"` to both the controls if you are using .Net Version 4.0 or higher.
Hope this helps.